# PhoneGap on Android: camera.getPicture success proceedure not being called

Tags: android, camera, cordova

I'm checking out PhoneGap API for Android and was trying out the camera sample application example and installed in my Android Phone (2.1 Galaxy S). However after running the app and taking a picture the image was not retrieved. From what I understand in the code, after taking the picture, the image would be displayed in a 60x60 below the button. I tried printing out the base64 value in an alert message but I didn't get any response as well (also no error alerts were displayed). Is there something I missed or should be doing? or did modify the camera function for Android (I'm ueing PhoneGap 0.9.2)

Aside from that, the rest of the function seem to work properly. I was able to load and display the images from the library, etc.

Sample code can be found in the url below
http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried using FILE_URI as return value but there still seems to be a problem. After taking a picture there was still no return call made to the success method.

I've already run a lot of test and there are a (very few) times that the camera function worked. However most of the time the process just hanged. I'll try testing this on a different phone model to see if the result is the same

Comment: I've tested it on a friend's LG Optimus(2.2) and HTC Hero (1.6) and ended up with the same result. Is the sample posted in the PhoneGap docu page outdated?

Answer (score 5):

Try 'uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"' in your manifest file and use 'destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI' for phonegap's getPicture call. I had the same problem and adding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with HTC Desire and basic PhoneGap camera example, but when I changed `getPhoto()` to use `FILE_URI`:

```
function getPhoto() {   
  navigator.camera.getPicture(
      onPhotoURISuccess, 
      onFail, 
      { quality: 50, destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI }
  );
}
```

... it started to work fine.

Comment: worked for me also. we need to add destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out that the `onActivityResult` I had defined in my Activity was silently interfering with the DroidGap functionality. A `super.onActivityResult()` call got things working again.